# Is there a way to fix a date error using Symfony 4?

Tags: date, command, symfony4, php-7.2

I'm working on a project as a back-end developer using PHP 7.2.11 and Symfony 4.2.3

My goal is to showcase events (concerts, festivals...) from data I grab from an API on an interactive map.

This is the result I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOzh4.jpg

To import the data from the API, I use a **for loop** going from 1 to 7 (corresponding to days) and adding days to the today's date.

This date will be used as a parameter to grab the events occuring from today to the next 7 days.

Problem is: I get the following error running my custom symfony command 
**php bin/console import:mapado** :

> 2019-03-26T12:08:34+01:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "import:mapado". Message: "Notice: Undefined index: address"

**The error is due to a date not existing and then refering to an inexistant address.**

I tried to change the parameters in my first for loop, with days going either to 8 or to 6 but it didn't change the output error.

I change the custom date parameter (from my loop) from the API url to the default parameter and everything is working with default (but it only gets the events for the 3 next days).

Here is the parameter I use:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cFXC.png

From: https://api.mapado.net/v2/docs#operation/getActivityCollection

And how an element from the API looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz8Cc.png

**This is the code I've written:**

```js
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        for ($jour = 0; $jour <= 7; $jour++) {
           // problem is here
            $futureDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$jour.' days'));

            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mapado.net/v2/activities?fields=@id,title,shortDate,nextDate,activityType,locale,description,address&itemsPerPage=1000&when=".$futureDay."&periodOfDay=evening",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Authorization: Bearer MTMwZWJiODFiZjA4YTcyOGY2ZmMzMGYwOTQyYWM2NDZjODVlNDg1MzU0MzE3M2I4MTdiMDQyZjU5MDVkZjFjZA",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Conent-Type: application/json",
                    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Postman-Token: 55672a19-0ffc-4fe6-a866-3e15c3df9dae"
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            $mapado_events = json_decode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($mapado_events['hydra:member']); $i++) {

                if ($mapado_events['hydra:member'][$i]['locale'] == 'fr') {

                    $mapado_id = $mapado_events['hydra:member'][$i]['@id'];
                    $mapado_date = \date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mapado_events['hydra:member'][$i]['nextDate']));

                    $result = $this->getContainer()
                        ->get('doctrine')
                        ->getRepository(MapadoIDs::class)
                        ->findOneBy(['mapado_id' => $mapado_id]);

                    if ($result == null) {
                        echo 'event existe pas, ajout en bdd'.PHP_EOL;
                        $MapadoIDs = new MapadoIDs();
                        $MapadoIDs->setMapadoId($mapado_id);
                        $this->em->persist($MapadoIDs);

                        $mapado = json_decode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

                        $event = new Event();

                        $event->setLongitude($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['address']['longitude']);
                        $event->setLatitude($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['address']['latitude']);
                        $event->setTitle($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['title']);
                        $event->setDate($mapado_date);
                        $event->setFormattedAddress($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['address']['formattedAddress']);
                        $event->setCity($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['address']['city']);
                        $event->setLocale($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['locale']);
                        $event->setActivityType($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['activityType']);
                        $event->setDescription($mapado['hydra:member'][$i]['description']);

                        $this->em->persist($event);                     
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->em->flush();

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #: " . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
}
```

for better readability:

https://pastebin.com/CTu5gb8t

Expected result is a json output in my console. 
Actual result is an error thrown preventing me from inserting results into my database.

**Could you tell me if I'm missing something that could result in this error ?**

It's a long and detailed post so that you can understand better my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my problem and it was not a date problem.

The problem was with the **itemsPerPage** query parameter requesting too much data and then throwing an error.

I set it up to 400 and everything is working as expected.